# Teamcity MsBuild generates wrong cspkg file

Tags: azure, msbuild, teamcity

I am trying to build and Deploy our solution to Azure using TeamCity.
When I Build the azure solution (Web.Azure.ccproj) using TC, it always generates wrong file like Web.Azure.ccproj.cspkg in Release\app.publish folder. I am not understaing why it is generating a file like ccproj.cspkg. Rather it should have just generated Web.Azure.cspkg.

Note: when I try directly in command prompt (msbuild Web.Azure.ccproj /t:Publish) am able to see proper files generated.

Any reason why this is happening?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Strangely for me when I run the command directly on the build agent (i.e. from the command line) it generates the correct file but when run via TeamCity it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the generated files are different. However, if you are looking to deploy to Azure Cloud Services from TeamCity, maybe [this link](http://blog.lytzen.name/2013/08/continuous-deployment-to-azure-cloud.html) will help.

The linked post has a powershell script that will deploy the solution and you can include that as a build step in TeamCity. The script deals with having different Live and UAT environments etc, which you may not need.

Comment: Hi Frans, 
Thanks for the response. I am using somewhat similar powershell script to deploy our application. But difference is I am adding one extra build step in TC to Build my azure application. 
I tried building application using powershell script as shown in the link that you provided, but still the same result.
I am seriously not getting why the file is being generated like this  when built inside TC.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we're building the entire solution with a Visual Studio (.sln) runner and it builds the Azure projects fine.

Some of our parameters:

```
Targets: Rebuild
Configuration: Dev (Could be Stage or Release per our environments)
Command line parameters: /p:TargetProfile=Dev /P:Configuration=Dev
```

The last set of parameters are where I originally got stuck.  We have profiles for Azure projects and configurations for the entire solution.  We need both to get the right packages created.